# Error during creation of a new transaction in Corda V2

Tags: corda

I encountered one error when I created a new transaction with Corda V2.0, from the sender's server log, it shows below error

[WARN ] 2018-05-15T09:34:47,366Z [Messaging] messaging.NodeMessagingClient.sendWithRetry - Reached the maximum number of retries (3) for message ClientMessageImpl[messageID=0, durable=true, address=internal.peers.4qWch9xxxV,userID=null,properties=TypedProperties[platform-version=2,corda-vendor=Corda Open Source,release-version=2.0.0,platform-topic=platform.session,session-id=0,_AMQ_DUPL_ID=dd1d6efb-dd71-4d34-9686-fecdb8d72671]] redelivery to internal.peers.4qWchxxxEmV

In recipient's log, we can see the transaction's dependency(attachment) is retrieved and stored successfully but there is no information about transaction's process(I think this log information should be provided from Corda by default).

We are using raft notaries cluster and I didn't find any transaction information in 3 notaries logs.

So we are not sure where is the root cause for that messaging error. Anyone can help?

Comment: I’m suspecting the notaries are not running or not reachable. I would check the notary logs to see if the notaries are up and then try to reach the notary P2P port from the client node (e.g. `nc -vz <notary-host> <port>`).

Comment: We have double checked Notaries are up and running. We don't have any warm or error in the logs and we have performed a portqry from all nodes to notaries and they are listening correctly in the ports used in node.conf files.
Any other idea?

Comment: This is a bug. It is being tracked here: https://r3-cev.atlassian.net/browse/CORDA-1527.

Answer (score 0):

In Corda 3, there is a bug which means that after rebooting a Raft notary cluster, the Raft cluster ends up partitioned with multiple leaders and it no longer services client requests.

You can track the solution to this issue on Corda's JIRA board: https://r3-cev.atlassian.net/browse/CORDA-1527.